# ReactDOM / getDOMNode() instead of jQuery?

Tags: reactjs

How should I structure this ReactJS code to use ReactDOM / `getDOMNode()` instead of jQuery. This plays a sound when a button is pressed.

Not sure if I should put the `.play()` in `myAudioObject` and access it via Refs, or the other way... pass Refs with `.getDomNode()` into `myPlayButton`.

Also, is using jQuery they way i have it below considered bad practice with ReactJS?

```
var myAudioObject = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         <audio id="mySoundClip" preload="auto">
            <source src='audio/thing.mp3'></source>
            Your browser does not support audio.
         </audio>
      );
   } 
});


var myPlayButton = React.createClass({
   handleClickPlay: function() {
      var audio = $("#mySoundClip")[0];
      audio.load(); // This reloads the audio tag in the DOM, so also reloads ReactJS component.
      audio.play();
   },

   render: function() {
      return (
         <button onClick={this.handleClickPlay}>Play</button> 
      );
   } 
}); 


var App = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            <myAudioObject />
            <myPlayButton />
         </div>
      );
  } 
}); 


React.renderComponent((
   <App />
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track, try using refs like this (or use [flux](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html)) - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uu6zeqg/1/)

```
var myAudioObject = React.createClass({
    play: function () {
        var audio = this.getDOMNode();
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <audio preload="auto">
                <source src='audio/thing.mp3'></source>
                Your browser does not support audio.
            </audio>
        );
    } 
});

var myPlayButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
             <button onClick={this.props.handleClickPlay}>Play</button> 
        );
    } 
}); 

var App = React.createClass({
    handleClickPlay: function() {
        this.refs.audioObject.play()
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <myAudioObject ref="audioObject" />
                <myPlayButton handleClickPlay={this.handleClickPlay} />
            </div>
        );
    } 
});
```

using jQuery like that is frowned upon, because it quickly becomes unclear whats depending on what.